# Not getting this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Print all details of the 16th order placed by each customer if any.

How to print exact 16th Order?

```
SELECT COUNT(orderId) 
FROM orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```

Comment: check rank function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a `CTE` and `RANK` to create a list of all orderId's, customerID's and their "order" as you named it.
Then we fetch those entries from the entire result whose order is 16.

```
WITH result AS
(
  SELECT orderId, customerID, 
  RANK() OVER
    (PARTITION BY customerID 
     ORDER BY orderId) AS rnk 
  FROM orders
)
SELECT orderId, customerID 
FROM result 
WHERE rnk=16 
GROUP BY orderId, customerID
ORDER BY customerID;
```

For customerID's having less than 16 orders, nothing will be selected.

We can also use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK` in the above query, this makes no difference in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use offset like:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 15;
```

and set the `OFFSET` value to 15 so it skips the first 15 values and prints  from the 16th value and limit it to only one row by setting the `LIMIT` value to 1

Comment: very simple and neat.. should've go for this one.

Comment: Its ask the details of exact 16th orders details by every customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from 
(
  SELECT *, 
  DENSE_RANK() 
  OVER(
    PARTITION BY customerID 
    ORDER BY orderID
  ) my_rank 
  FROM orders
) as myTable 
where my_rank = 16 
order by CustomerID;
```